# Reading serialport data without missing any data and Parsing

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a system that sends data over serialport every 200ms. I am trying to read that using serialport data read. I have two types of data to read and parse it. First data sequence looks like this

> $System1;c62;23.34;E-1;E-2;-56.67;567;

Second data sequence looks like this

> \u0006\u0001\0d\o?\"\0$?##STA\r\nSystemLevel:Run\r\nstatus:1\r\n................\r\nSTOP##

First sequence data will be sent every 200ms and second sequence data will be sent every 20 sec in between first data sequence.

I am trying to read serialport as below

```
  void ConfigcomPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        StringBuilder charSrting = new StringBuilder();
        //string Data;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);
        string Data = configcomPort.ReadExisting();

        if (Data.StartsWith("$System1"))
        {
            try
            {
                string[] splitdata = Data.Split(';', '\r', '\n');

                double.TryParse(splitdata[3], NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out Position1);
                double.TryParse(splitdata[4], NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out position2);
                supplyVoltage = splitdata[2];
                if (splitdata[1].StartsWith("C"))
                {
                    batteryStatus = BatteryStatus[1];
                    BatteryPercent = double.Parse(splitdata[1].Substring(1, 2));
                }

                NotifyDataReceived(system, value.position1);
                UpdateBatteryStatus(BatteryPercent);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                string test = ex.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
           try
            {
                string[] Statussplit = Data.Split(';', ':', '\r', '\n')
                //trying to parse second sequence here.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                string test = ex.Message;
            }
         }
     }
```

The problem is i am not able to read second sequence properly. The data is missing. I am able to receive first sequence and parse it but inbetween i get second sequence that is not properly receiving. i always miss some data in second sequence so unable parse it.

Is there any way to solve this issue??  I tried with "bytestoread" but still it is same. 
is there any best method to read all the sequence and parse it out??

Regards,
ram.

Comment: `configcomPort.ReadExisting();` may return all or part of the "message". It could read both messages at once (sequentially). You may need to build a buffer with the content of multiple reads and only try to parse when you have gotten a complete message.

Comment: Data is not guaranteed to come in one chunk.  Your code has to be able to verify you got the entire response.

Comment: As @jdweng said, data is not guaranteed to come in one chunk. I resolved similar problem by maintaining a string as a member variable and appending to it on every DataReceived. It looks for NewLine as a terminating/end of message and post that string is sent for further processing. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698237/c-sharp-serial-datarecieved-data-is-in-pieces

Comment: Are these messages terminated by any non-printing characters? like ETX, EOT, or ACK?

Comment: @Whistler yes the second sequence messages are terminated with checksum and starts with some protocol data with non printing characters .

Comment: @jdweng, Praveen Raghuvanshi Thanks for you suggestions. I will try as you suggested.

Comment: Are the messages proceeded with a byte count or the messages fixed length.  You need to know where the checksum is located.  Usually the messages have a byte count when the message are variable lengths.

Comment: @jdweng One sequence is fixed length and another one is variable length.

Comment: The sending application has to indicate the length either by one of three methods 1) Known length : each message type has a predetermined length 2) A byte count is sent.  Usually at the beginning but can be in the middle 3)The data is terminated with a known character(s).  When a connection is made one or more of the methods above can be used in same connection  You have to wait until the end of each message before processing.  A message may contain one or more messages (or a piece of a message) so you have to save the pieces and combine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions i managed to solve it by reading data into buffer